# R RefClass inherit from standard classes?

Tags: r, inheritance

Is it not possible to inherit from standard classes

As an example the following class definition

```
myNewClass <- setRefClass(
  "myNewClass",
  contains = "numeric",
  fields = list(
    desc = "character"
  )
)
```

results in this error when creating an object:

```
obj1 <- myNewClass()
obj1
Error in as.environment(x) : invalid 'pos' argument
```

Similar if "numeric is replaced by "character" or "data.frmae" except the error message changes.

Is this just not possible in R due to class sealing or something else or do I have a bug in the code which I can't see?

Comment: you are creating a reference class, which typically would inherit from other reference classes, if at all. Maybe you want to use `setClass` rather than `setRefClass` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm aware of the differences between S4 and RefClass in R. I know that typicaly one would inherit from other refclasses, but is there no possibility to inherit from Standard classes in order to use e.g. the arth. operators?

Comment: Does really nobody has this issue as well?